# Speeding up a pandas rolling referencing another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I'd like some feedback on how to optimize the following pandas computation:

We have a fixed index set `I` and a `lookback`.  In addition we have a pd.Series `index` its median over lookback, `index_MEDIAN`, and a large list of pandas data frames. All series/dataframes have I as their index. Each dataframe has the column `value`. Let `D` be one such dataframe..

For every row of `D` we take the corresponding value `m` in `index_MEDIAN` and sum all value entries present in the lookback window, subject to the condition that the running value in the `index` series is greater than `m`. In other words whenever the Index value is greater than the median of the lookback we sum the corresponding value row in `D`.

To shed more light, here is a sketch of the implementation described above

```
  def sumvals(x)

      S = (D['value'].loc[x.index] >= self.index_median.loc[x.index[-1]])
 
      return sum(S*(x-self.index_median.loc[x.index[-1]]))

   D['value'].rolling(lookback).apply(sumvals)
```

The list of dataframes is quite huge and I've noticed this way of computing this quantity takes an excessive amount of time. I suspect the issue is related to the fact that this implementation uses `.loc` a lot. Hence

> Is there another way to express this solution without having to reference an external Series so much?

Either way, any kind of optimization suggestion is welcome.

Edit. Here is an example dataset with the respective computation.

```
lookback = 3
Index = pd.Series([1,-2,8,-10,3,4,5, 10, -20, 3])
Index_median = Index.rolling(lookback).median
Values = pd.Series([1,2,2,3,0,9,10, 8, 20, 9])
```

The resulting computation on *Values* should yield

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     2.0
3    13.0
4     0.0
5     6.0
6    11.0
7    12.0
8    23.0
9    28.0
```

For example the value in the 5th row is 6. Why? The Index_median value in the 5th row is 3. The 3-lookback in the 5th row is the sequence 9 , 0, 3. The  values >= are 3 and 9 so this comprises our sum for the 5th row 3-3+9-3 = 6. Similarly for the last row the index median is 3. The last three rows in Values are all greater than 3 and sum up to 34 - 3*3 = 28.

Comment: `apply` will always be slower than the core methods written in C, can you show your sample dataset with expected output?

Comment: @Manakin See if the added example helps. I realize only now that it's crucial to have one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['I'] = pd.Series([1,-2,8,-10,3,4,5, 10, -20, 3])
df['I_median'] = df['I'].rolling(lookback).median()
df['Values'] = pd.Series([1,2,2,3,0,9,10, 8, 20, 9])
```

Now add shifted columns for the 'Value' column

```
# add one column for every lookback    
for colno in range(lookback):  

        # shift the column by one and deduct the median
        df['n'+ str(colno)] = df['Values'].shift(colno) - df['I_median']

        # remove all negative numbers (where value is smaller than median)
        df['n'+ str(colno)] = df['n'+ str(colno)].where(df['n'+ str(colno)]> 0, 0)

# sum up across the new columns
df['result'] = df[df.columns[-lookback:]].sum(axis=1)
```

df.result contains your result and equals

```
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     2.0
3    13.0
4     0.0
5     6.0
6    11.0
7    12.0
8    23.0
9    28.0
Name: result, dtype: float64
```

## Edit: without shifted columns in data frame

```
df['result'] = 0

for colno in range(lookback):  
        # shift the column by one and deduct the median
        df['temp'] = df['Values'].shift(colno) - df['I_median']

        # remove all negative numbers (where value is smaller than median)
        df['temp'] = df['temp'].where(df['temp']> 0, 0)

        # sum up across the new columns
        df['result'] = df['result'] + df['temp']
```

## Performance

- 1m rows in dataframe
- 1000 lookback

```
lookback = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['I'] = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=1000000))
df['I_median'] = df['I'].rolling(lookback).median()
df['Values'] = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=1000000))
```

runs in about 14s.

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks. Do you see any efficient solution without creating new columns as well? Issue is lookback is ~1000 in my application

Comment: This approach can be easily adapted to sum up the result on the go without adding the columns to the data frame but I expect performance would be similar, although it would require less memory. , Let me know if the current causes performance or memory issues with your data.

Answer (score 2):

```
def sumvals(x)
      m =  self.index_median.loc[x.index[-1]]
      condition = (x.index >= m)
      return sum(x[condition]-m)

   D['value'].rolling(lookback).apply(sumvals)
```

When we are taking sum of all value entries present in the lookback window there is no need to compared them with self.index.  Also from your description if your taking value row in D then you can

```
return sum(x[condition])
```

directly instead.

Another soln is that you can convert whole operation into numpy for speeding up the rolling operation.
Checkout the [numpy_ext](https://github.com/3jane/numpy_ext) package for this

Answer (score 2):

.loc is slow and apply is slow.
It seems to me that you can achieve what you want using vectorised functions and operations over columns without a row-by-row-apply and loc-lookups.

It is hard to tell without a real data example as @Manakin suggested.
But I tried to re-create your question with an example and solve it according to your description.

```
# lookback window    
lookback = 3 

# Fixed Index
I = [5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 10]

# Dataframe with value column, Index added as column for convenience
df = pd.DataFrame({'I': I, 
                   'value':[6,5,4,3,2,1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
                   index=I)

# Median over lookback window
df['I_median'] = df.I.rolling(lookback).median()
```

yields

```
|    |  I    |  value   | I_median
|----|-------|----------|----------|
| 5  | 5     | 6        | NaN      |
| 2  | 2     | 5        | NaN      |
| 1  | 1     | 4        | 2.0      |
| 4  | 4     | 3        | 2.0      |
| 2  | 2     | 2        | 2.0      |
| 4  | 4     | 1        | 4.0      |
| 1  | 1     | 2        | 2.0      |
| 2  | 2     | 3        | 2.0      |
| 1  | 1     | 4        | 1.0      |
| 10 | 10    | 5        | 2.0      |

# Check if Index is greater than median
df['I_gt'] = df.I > df.I_median

# set all rows to 0 where median is greater than index
df['filtered_val'] = df.value.where(df.I_gt, 0)

|    | I  | value | I_median | I_gt  | filtered_val |
|----|----|-------|----------|-------|--------------|
| 5  | 5  | 6     | NaN      | False | 0            |
| 2  | 2  | 5     | NaN      | False | 0            |
| 1  | 1  | 4     | 2.0      | False | 0            |
| 4  | 4  | 3     | 2.0      | True  | 3            |
| 2  | 2  | 2     | 2.0      | False | 0            |
| 4  | 4  | 1     | 4.0      | False | 0            |
| 1  | 1  | 2     | 2.0      | False | 0            |
| 2  | 2  | 3     | 2.0      | False | 0            |
| 1  | 1  | 4     | 1.0      | False | 0            |
| 10 | 10 | 5     | 2.0      | True  | 5            |
```

Then simply do a rolling sum over the filtered column.

```
df.filtered_val.rolling(lookback).sum()
```

Comment: I think this code does not match the description. Take the second last value (4). The fixed median for this window is 1. The values in the lookback are 4,3 ,2. All are greater than 1 and hence we sum them up. I.e the median remains fixed in the lookback window.

Comment: @Jernej could you clarify "subject to the condition that the running value in the index series is greater than m" in your spec. are you referring to the value of the index (as I have implemented it) or the value-column (which your comment seems to suggest). If it is the latter, then then df['I_gt'] = df.I > df.I_median needs to be changed to df['I_gt'] = df.value > df.I_median

Comment: "whenever the Index value is greater than the median": it's unclear if you mean the value of the Index (my column I) or the value in row (my column value). Perhaps edit your question and refer to your value column by another name, e.g. 'a' or 'b'. And illustrate what role the Index-column and Index-values play in your algorithm.

Comment: @tomaniizer I've added an example that should, hopefully help to clarify the computation I am looking for.

Comment: Thank you @Jernej. I have added a second answer which returns your result using only vectorized operations. I expect it to be several orders of magnitude faster than the row/apply/loc version.

Comment: In the general context, .apply is not always slow and can outperform numpy, for example in turning a pd.Series into string using .apply(str). But yes, in this context np is great!